# Merge two columns based on a table value

Tags: postgresql, join, merge, union

I'm trying to merge french strings (language ID 1) into one column. So far, I'm able to get french strings in `table1.title` and `table2.translated_topic`, but am not sure how to concatenate them.

Ver: Postgres 9.6.0

**Source table schemas:**

Table 1: `knowledgebase_topics`

```
id | title            | language_id |
------------------------------------
64   | The Topic      |    91       |  
65   | The Topic 2    |    91       |           
62   | Le fav sujet   |     1       |          
63   | Le fav sujet 2 |     1       |          
61   | le bonjour     |     1       |
```

Table 2: `knowledgebase_topics_translations`

```
id | translated_topic| knowledgebase_topic_id | language_id |
-------------------------------------------------------------
   | Le sujet        |          64            |     1       | 
   | Le sujet 2      |          65            |     1       |
   | Fav The Topic   |          62            |     91      |
   | Fav The Topic 2 |          63            |     91      |
```

---

Given the following Query:

```
SELECT title, translated_topic, "kbt".language_id, "kbtt".language_id
FROM knowledgebase_topics as "kbt" 
LEFT JOIN knowledgebase_topics_translations as "kbtt" on ("kbtt".knowledgebase_topic_id = "kbt".id) 
INNER JOIN knowledgebase_topics_organizations as "kbto" on ("kbto".knowledgebase_topic_id = "kbt".id) 
WHERE "kbto"."organization_id" = 1 
AND to_tsvector("kbt".title) @@ to_tsquery('le') 
OR to_tsvector("kbtt".translated_topic) @@ to_tsquery('le') 
AND "kbt".language_id = 1 
OR "kbtt".language_id = 1;
```

I get the following results:

```
     title      | translated_topic | language_id | language_id 
----------------+------------------+-------------+-------------
 The Topic      | Le sujet         |          91 |           1
 The Topic 2    | Le sujet 2       |          91 |           1
 Le fav sujet   | Fav The Topic    |           1 |          91
 Le fav sujet 2 | Fav The Topic 2  |           1 |          91
 le bonjour     |                  |           1 |
```

**Desired results:** `table1.title` and `table2.translated_topics` have been merged based on `language_id == 1`. Both tables have a language ID column.

```
     title      | language_id
----------------+--------------
 Le sujet       | 1
 Le sujet 2     | 1
 Le fav sujet   | 1
 Le fav sujet 2 | 1
 le bonjour     | 1
```

How can I do this?

---

Note: I do not simply want to check lang IDs = 1, such as

```
and "kbt".language_id = 1 AND (instead of OR) "kbtt".language_id = 1;
```

Because this results in 2 missing records from `table 2` of language ID 1:

```
     title      | translated_topic | language_id | language_id 
----------------+------------------+-------------+-------------
 Le fav sujet   | Fav The Topic    |           1 |          91
 Le fav sujet 2 | Fav The Topic 2  |           1 |          91
 le bonjour     |                  |           1 |
```

---

So, I've got it working... but is this performant?

```
SELECT title, "kbt".language_id
FROM knowledgebase_topics as "kbt" 
INNER JOIN knowledgebase_topics_organizations as "kbto" on ("kbto".knowledgebase_topic_id = "kbt".id) 
WHERE "kbto"."organization_id" = 1
AND to_tsvector("kbt".title) @@ to_tsquery('le') 
AND "kbt".language_id = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT translated_topic, "kbtt".language_id 
FROM knowledgebase_topics_translations as "kbtt"
INNER JOIN knowledgebase_topics_organizations as "kbto" on ("kbto".knowledgebase_topic_id = "kbtt".id) 
WHERE "kbto"."organization_id" = 1
AND to_tsvector("kbtt".translated_topic) @@ to_tsquery('le')
AND "kbtt".language_id = 1;
```

Gives output:

```
     title      | language_id 
----------------+-------------
 le bonjour     |           1
 Le fav sujet   |           1
 Le fav sujet 2 |           1
 Le sujet       |           1
 Le sujet 2     |           1
(5 rows)
```

Comment: So you want a result set which only has 'language_id' 1 ? OR a result set that only has the rows that have 'language_id' 1 concatenated and the other values not?

Comment: I want all rows from `table1.title` and `table2.translated_topic` whose language_id == 1, and meet the other contstraints (`tsvector, tsquery, org ID match, etc). I'd like the result sets in a single column like `merged`

Comment: @MeesKluivers see above for clarification

Comment: @MeesKluivers @MeesKluivers see above for clarification. Basically I want to merge the results of two table columns where `language_id = 1.`

Comment: Maybe you should check out CASE. something like CASE WHEN kbt.langid = 1 AND kbtt.langid = 1 THEN .. etc. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Setting up an environment to answer the question

First, observe how we best describe the problem with concise DDL. Preferably in the future, you'll learn how to write questions like this..

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE knowledgebase_topics AS
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
  (64,'The Topic',91),
  (65,'The Topic 2',91),
  (62,'Le fav sujet',1),
  (63,'Le fav sujet 2',1),
  (61,'le bonjour',1)
) AS t(knowledgebase_topic_id, title, language_id);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE knowledgebase_topics_translations AS
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
  ('Le sujet'       ,64,1  ),
  ('Le sujet 2'     ,65,1  ),
  ('Fav The Topic'  ,62,91 ),
  ('Fav The Topic 2',63,91 )
) AS t(translated_topic, knowledgebase_topic_id, language_id);
```

Then you need only tell us what you want and we can get a working environment up easily and answer your question. No English required! Easier on both of us.

## The solution

Here we use a `UNION ALL` we wrap that in a `SELECT` so we can sort by id, and easily change in one place the `language` that you're looking for.

```
SELECT title, language_id
FROM (
  SELECT knowledgebase_topic_id, title, language_id
  FROM knowledgebase_topics
  UNION ALL
  SELECT knowledgebase_topic_id, translated_topic, language_id
  FROM knowledgebase_topics_translations
) AS t(id, title, language_id)
WHERE language_id = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

### Output

```
     title      │ language_id 
────────────────┼─────────────
 le bonjour     │           1
 Le fav sujet   │           1
 Le fav sujet 2 │           1
 Le sujet       │           1
 Le sujet 2     │           1
(5 rows)
```

Comment: @Growler I would personally schema change this. I would pick a primary language -- you really have too anyway for the purposes of third party tools an *index language*. Then I would put the translations in a JSONB if they weren't being indexed. Or, I'd put them in separate columns based on their names and translations.. `CREATE TABLE movie_table ( id serial PRIMARY KEY, name text, fr text );`. etc. I would not join in the fashion. You have a primary table and a secondary table. I'm not sure why. And that you want to query them as if they were one tells me you're not sure why either.

Comment: Evan you went above and beyond in helping me (and hopefully others) by providing an answer to the question and an example for writing better questions. Much appreciated!!

Comment: You may also want to try dba.stackexchange.com, If you want to get information about performance and such. When you want a query, always provide the DDL to generate the query (the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT), or if you want performance advice (always make another question) and paste the query, and output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: Evan there is no `knowledgebase_topic_id` in the first table you're selecting: `knowledgebase_topics`. You may want to  change it to `id`

Comment: Also where should the check on `organization_id` exist?

Comment: I have no idea what `organization_id` is, it wasn't in your sample data. But, i changed knowledgebase_topics, to knowledgebase_topic_id because they seem to be linked in your data and keeping them similarly named makes the query easier to read and understand. I hate the name `id` for a pkey. If you feel differently though feel free to change it.